# Difference between Creating a new Result Source and configuring Search Result webpart Query

Tags: search, search-results, query, result-source, keywordquery

I have a subsite where I would need to return results. The results will be similar to the out of the box Local SharePoint Sites except that results will be coming from a specific subsite.

I know that the **Path:** is both used in the resulting query regardless whether I define it in Result Source or the Search Result webpart. What are the differences between defining a new result source compared to simple defining it the query of the search result webpart? It seems like it will achieve the same.

The contents of either approach have already been crawled by the Local SharePoint Site. I read some articles saying that creating a new result source will create an index for the subsite that I want, but isn't the same thing happening if I simply define the path as the parameter in my search result webpart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple explanation would be around reusability.

You can use the same filters in a Result Source and a query rule in a SRWP.  The benefit of a Result Source is that it can A) be set as the 'default' for that site and lower and B) can be reused in multiple SRWPs without having to write the query rule again and again (and have to change it multiple times when needed).

You can chain them so that the Result Source does most of the filtering and then the SRWP just adds a little more specific filtering at this specific location.